# Android BLE scan filters returning many MAC matches for 1 dev in a few secs - What is intended behavior?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

It's not clear from the documentation I've read what the intended behavior of BluetoothLE scans is. There's a particular device we're looking for, if I scan using name or MAC as a criterion I get dozens of results matching both -- is this an intended reflection of multiple device advertisements, or RSSI change or something?

```
ArrayList<ScanFilter> filter = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
filter.add(new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress("24:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX").build());
ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build();
bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filter, settings, leScanCallback);    // Yields 34 in 5 sec
```

Comment: Is the device actually advertising the service in its advertisement data? Existing in the gatt database after connecting to it is irrelevant.

Comment: @Emil - new to BT, didn't see in docs or guides that service filter only works if device decides to advertise service. Explains the lack of results, thanks! WIll edit the question to focus on whether the multiple results are expected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will get one callback per advertisement or pair of advertisement/scan response data.

You can therefore for example track rssi changes, or changes in the advertisement data.

Use for example https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings#MATCH_NUM_ONE_ADVERTISEMENT to modify that behaviour.